# IoT and NoSQL, I still don't get it

Tags: nosql, cloud, bigdata, iot

I'm trying to understand the benefit of NoSQL over RDBMS/Big Data for IoT in the context of a cloud application.
Imagine you have a set of sensors measuring the temperature and humidity, and the result is published over MQTT as:

```
{"sensorID": 123456789, "timestamp": "20240101T00:00:00+01:00", "temp": 15.1, "humidity": 49}
```

You also want to display some statistics on a website (averages, min/max, ...).

Why would you store the JSON you got from the sensors in a NoSQL DB? What kind of operations would you run on the NoSQL DB, other than running a job to insert the data in some kind of Big Data solution (like Redshift or BigQuery)? You can also use a serverless function or another piece of code, to transform the data and insert it directly in the Big Data DB, no?

Everywhere I see IoT as a use case for NoSQL DBs (like DynamoDB, MongoDB, Firestore, ...), but I don't see the benefit. I don know that those kind of databases are very good to store unstructured data (like when the JSON you receive is not always the same), but then you can create different tables in the RDBMS/Big Data databases?

I've been looking for a clear explanation (with examples or a use case), but I was not able to find one that answered my questions.

I hope someone can explain the pro/cons  here and why you would prefer one database type over the others.